# Element API: PHP Error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Trying to get this json api to work for us and keep running into issues. Here, when trying to list all items, it throws the following PHP error:

> Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) in /home/accesstrucks/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php on line 618

There are only 100 listings currently, but this is just for testing. Which is nothing compared to how many listings there will be when live.

Here's my code:

```
return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'alltrucks.json' => [
      'elementType' => 'Entry',
      'criteria' => ['section' => 'trucks'],
      'paginate' => false,
      'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
        return [
          $entry->year.' '.$entry->manufacturer.' '.$entry->model,
          (string)$entry->author,
          !empty((string)$entry->category[0]) ? (string)$entry->category[0] : null, 
          !empty($entry->listingPhotos[0]->url) ? str_replace('/images/uploads/listings/', '', $entry->listingPhotos[0]->url) : null,
          ($entry->saleType=='new') ? '0' : '1',
          (string)$entry->featured,
          ($entry->saleType->label=='new') ? '0' : '1',
          $entry->transmission,
          (string)$entry->dateUpdated,
          $entry->mileage,
          $entry->price
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `php.ini` file's [`memory_limit`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting is set to `32M`.

You'll want to bump that up to something higher like `256M`.

Comment: Am i running a the risk of overloading the memory on the site though? It seems surprising that such a simple query would be so demanding on memory.

Comment: Probably not? 32M is a pretty low memory limit setting.

Comment: Good to know. Updated it and its running fine now, as would be expected.